# Unity Spawning hazards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a script to spawn object on platform randomly.[image], The spawning thing works fine, The second script is to disable the spawning objects(hazards) when they hit the platform. They disapear like they should, but after a couple of hazards spawned, they keep spawning i see that in the console, but not on my Scene/Game screen. [image]

**The code for the spawning:`**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnHazards : MonoBehaviour {

    #region Variables
    //Public
    //Private
    [SerializeField]
    private float minX = 0.0f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float maxX = 0.0f;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] hazards;
    [SerializeField]
    private float timeBetweenSpawns = 0.0f;
    private bool canSpawn = false;
    private int amountOfHazardsToSpawn = 0;
    private int hazardsToSpawn = 0;
    #endregion

    #region UnityFunctions
    void Start() {   
        canSpawn = true;
    }

    void Update() {    
        if(canSpawn == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine("GenerateHazard");
        }    
    }
    #endregion
    private IEnumerator GenerateHazard()
    {
        canSpawn = false;
        timeBetweenSpawns = Random.Range(0.5f, 2.0f); //Testing values
        amountOfHazardsToSpawn = Random.Range(1, 6);  //Testing values

        for(int i =0; i < amountOfHazardsToSpawn; i++)
        {
            Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(minX, maxX), 15.0f, 0.0f); // generate spawn position
            Instantiate(hazards[hazardsToSpawn], spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);  //spawn hazards
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenSpawns);
        canSpawn = true;  
    }
}
```

**the code for disabling them after collision:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HazardCollisionFunctions : MonoBehaviour {

    #region Variables
    //Public

    //Private
    #endregion

     #region UnityFunctions
    private void Start()
    {

    }

    private void Update()
    {

    }
    #endregion

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Platform")
        {
            this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I took the code you provided and put it in an empty Unity project. I did not experience the cubes stopping spawning at all, so I feel like the issue may lie elsewhere.

I was able to simplify the looping of the coroutine for you though, which may avoid some issues in the future:

```
private IEnumerator GenerateHazard()
{
    while (true)
    {
        timeBetweenSpawns = Random.Range(0.5f, 2.0f); //Testing values
        amountOfHazardsToSpawn = Random.Range(1, 6);  //Testing values

        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfHazardsToSpawn; i++)
        {
            Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(minX, maxX), 15.0f, 0.0f); // generate spawn position
            Instantiate(hazards[hazardsToSpawn], spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);  //spawn hazards
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenSpawns);
    }
}
```

With this code, you only need to call `StartCoroutine(GenerateHazard());` once in the `Start` function.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the problem comes from calling the coroutine...
I don't have Unity on my current PC, so I can't test it, but try this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnHazards : MonoBehaviour {

    #region Variables
    //Public
    //Private
    [SerializeField]
    private float minX = 0.0f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float maxX = 0.0f;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] hazards;
    [SerializeField]
    private float timeBetweenSpawns = 0.0f;
    //private bool canSpawn = false;
    private int amountOfHazardsToSpawn = 0;
    private int hazardsToSpawn = 0;
    #endregion

    #region UnityFunctions
    void Start() {   
        //canSpawn = true;
    }

    void Update() {    
        timeBetweenSpawns -= Time.deltaTime;
        //if(canSpawn == true)
        if(timeBetweenSpawns < 0.0f)
        {
            //StartCoroutine("GenerateHazard");
            GenerateHazard();
        }    
    }
    #endregion
    private void GenerateHazard()
    {
        //canSpawn = false;
        timeBetweenSpawns = Random.Range(0.5f, 2.0f); //Testing values
        amountOfHazardsToSpawn = Random.Range(1, 6);  //Testing values

        for(int i =0; i < amountOfHazardsToSpawn; i++)
        {
            Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(minX, maxX), 15.0f, 0.0f); // generate spawn position
            Instantiate(hazards[hazardsToSpawn], spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);  //spawn hazards
        }

        //yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenSpawns);
        //canSpawn = true;  
    }
}
```